# what is the best image for db: and db_backup for sqlite on docker-compose?

Tags: docker, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I developed an app on rails 5 and now I want to make an docker image of the app. I read some tutorials and all of them compose with postgras. I want to know what is the best image for sqlite and backup.
The current docker-compose.yml is like this:

`version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: sadmad/ibuy7:1.0
    volumes:
      - ./file_storage:/app/public/system/
      - assets:/app/public/assets/
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=...
  nginx:
    ports:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.production.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      default:
      nginx_default:
        aliases:
          Ibuy7
volumes:
  assets:
networks:
  nginx_default:
    external: true`

Comment: What do you mean by best image for sqlite and backup? You should install sqlite in your own image and use it.

Comment: Ok but there is more that 10 different image of sqlite is on docker, but none of them are official! 
I change my way and use postgres. It have official image and more than 100K downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question `sqlite` dbs are file based DBs and they are updated using libraries. So the only thing that matters for them is the file location, you don't access them over network. So you don't need any additional image or service for hosting sqlite db

The only thing you need to make sure that your image/service where you need to access the sqlite DB has the required libraries. You can then use volumes to save the DB on host if needed. So your `sadmad/ibuy7:1.0` image should have the required libraries.

Also if you want to use network based DB then you should use the official `mysql` or `postgres` images

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use the image of https://github.com/jayniz/docker-postgres-s3-backup-via-cron to do cron backups to S3